# How to make a method accessable to only one class?

Tags: oop, language-agnostic

Let's say I have a class Top and a class Bottom. Some "outside code" can call a method of class Top, and this will result in class Top accessing class Bottom's method. But how to make sure what it only works this way, and that nobody other than Top will not try to access Bottom directly?

Here is an illustration: [image]

If I'll make Bottom private, Top would not be able to access it. If I'll make Bottom public, everyone will be able to do it. Is there anything in between of these two? I heard you guys like to draw UML diagrams, but is there any way to inforce your design right in the IDE? Why? When this will change?

Comment: What language do you want to implement that? Or do you want rather a paradigm, for use in any OO language?

Comment: I'll easily migrate to a language you'll name if it makes this easier.

Comment: in C#, and  C++ too as I remember, you have Nested Types which is I think what your asking for https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120.aspx

Comment: @kenny Looks like that's it. Make it a real answer, I'll mark it as accepted. And thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving my comment to a real answer on request.

In C#, and I'm pretty sure C++, it looks like you're looking for Nested Types.
msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120.aspx

```
public class Container
{
    public Container()
    {
         Nested nested = new Nested();
         nested.DoIt();
    }

    class Nested
    {
        private Container parent;

        public Nested()
        {
        }

        public Nested(Container parent)
        {
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        public void DoIt()
        {
        }
    }
}
```